# Does updating applications affect .desktop files?

Tags: updates, software-sources

I was wandering if .desktop files are affected when an application is updated or just the `/usr/bin/*` files? I'm making an menu with customized categories and it's not gonna work is the categories in .desktop files are reset to default when an application is updated.

Comment: @DKBose That sounds like a correct answer to me, so feel free to put it up as one.

Comment: See my comment on the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.desktop` files is in really part of the package itself, so of course the `.desktop` will b updated within the package.

Indeed the `.desktop` files can be found in these different places:

1. `/usr/share/applications`
2. `/usr/share/app-install/desktop`
3. `~/.local/share/applications`
4. `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`
5. `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/applications` if using Flatpak
6. and the `applications` subdirectory of any directory listed in the environment variable `XDG_DATA_DIRS`:

   ```
   echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS
   ```

But be care for some tips:

The `.desktop` in the `/usr/share/applciations` and those in `/usr/share/app-install/desktop` will be updated since those are related to system wide and those `.desktop` files are created when installing via `apt-get` or **Ubuntu Software Center**.

But to make sure that your file will not change you can put it in `~/.local/share/applications`, as those directories are for the user himself, so it'll not be changed unless you did it.

Related question: [Why are there redundant directories for .desktop files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624111/what-is-this-directory)

Comment: Actually, *not* changing/updating the local one is one of the most common reasons for duplicated Launcher icons.

Comment: All other .desktop items (except the custom alacarte .desktop file) are removed from ~/.local/share/applications and there are no duplicates in /usr/share/applications. I've deleted all default menus to make my own, and alacarte automatically makes a "duplicate" .desktop item which is visible in overview. I just want it in my alacarte menu, not in overview.