# AppKeys Ubuntu Gnome extension opens news instances of chrome

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, google-chrome, gnome-shell-extension

Ave!

I normally pin my chrome on (Super+1), Editor ( Super+2) and Firefox ( Super+3).

And thanks to this extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/413/dash-hotkeys/ i dont regret switching from Windows to Ubuntu.

Before upgrading from 14.10 to 15.04 it worked like this:

Super+1 opens chrome if not opened and focuses if already opened.
Super+2 opens chrome if not opened and focuses if already opened.
Super+3 opens chrome if not opened and focuses if already opened.

After the update only Chrome ( Super + 1 ) opens always new instance.
Firefox and Editor works the same.

Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 with gnome shell 3.16.1, the problems occurs on my Desktop and laptop.

Comment: As you manipulate with .desktop files, you might want to check how they're built and identify the feature that makes chrome different. There [are several locations](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626081/does-updating-applications-affect-desktop-files/626101#626101) for .desktop files, but most likely you would want to check the system level (1, 2) instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digged more for the problem so yes its a .desktop entry problem

After i edited :

```
vim /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

On the end of each config group

```
[Desktop Entry]
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
[NewIncognito Shortcut Group]
```

Added this:

```
## Custom
StartupWMClass=Google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: If this solved your question, please mark it as resolved :)